# Why is it not possible to modify an ArrayList when iterating over it with an enhanced for loop, whereas it's possible to do so with a normal for loop?

Tags: java

by "modify" I mean to add/remove elements from the ArrayList.

```
//works fine
private void setupStudentSchedule(){
   
    ArrayList<String> studentCourses = activeStudent.getCourses();
    for(int i = 0; i<studentCourses.size(); i++){
        String course = studentCourses.get(i);
        if(!mainApp.courseMap.containsKey(course)){
            activeStudent.getCourses().remove(course);
            continue;
        }
    
        //adding the courses to the schedule
        try{
            activeStudentSchedule.addCourseToSchedule(mainApp.courseMap.get(course));
        } 
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("problem in setupStudentSchedule()");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}

//results in a ConcurrentModificationException
private void setupStudentSchedule(){
    for(String course : activeStudent.getCourses()){

        if(!mainApp.courseMap.containsKey(course)){
            activeStudent.getCourses().remove(course);
            continue;
        }
    
        //adding the courses to the schedule
        try{
            activeStudentSchedule.addCourseToSchedule(mainApp.courseMap.get(course));
        } 
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println("problem in setupStudentSchedule()");
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I read some answers on similar questions, but i couldn't find an answer/comment that explained the reason behind this.

thanks!

Comment: Because there's no way to detect concurrent modification from an ordinary `for` loop.

Comment: Neither of these look good to me. I myself would use an iterator.

Comment: I think I'd use a `retainAll` first to remove all the things that need removing (`activeStudent.getCourses().retainAll(mainApp.courseMap.keySet());`), and then an enhanced for loop after.

Comment: The problem with the index-based for loop is that you have to take care not to skip over the element after the one you have just removed - you'd have this problem here.

Comment: @AndyTurner Thanks! that's pretty useful i didn't know about retainAll().

also you're correct, i just realized that the next element would have the same index of the element that just got removed, which will cause it to be skipped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to interpret your question.

### You wonder why the OpenJDK team designed it that way.

Let's say we have a list of 5 elements:

`[1,2,3,4,5]`.

While iterating through it (let's not focus on *how* we are doing that, just, that we are doing that somehow), you decide to add a '6' at the end during the loop that deals with the '3'.

This creates a bit of a dilemma. It is plausible that someone intended for the elements that are iterated through to be 'locked in' when you started the iteration, and that therefore you *do not* expect to run the loop for element 6.

It is *also* plausible that you want 6 to get looped over. If I state that some as yet undefined mechanism to loop through the list allows adding to the list in the middle of the loop and I take a microphone and interview 1000 java developers, asking them if they think it is likely that the added element will be looped over, or not looped over, that I get a 50/50 split.

That's bad. It's not a complete disaster - we can simply document that as yet undefined thing that loops a list does or does not include anything you add in the middle. Let's say for arguments sake that we do that, and document that it *does* include the element you add at the end.

So... what happens if we go back to `[1,2,3,4,5]` and during the loop that deals with the '3', we add a 0 **to the start** of the list? Now there are 4 plausible things that can happen:

1. Just like the first case, the 0 will be looped, too. Because it's 'before' the element we are on, it gets looped immediately afterwards. In other words, with this hypothetical code:

```
List list = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
loop list as int x { // this is hypothetical java code
  System.out.print(x);
  if (x == 3) list.addToFront(0);
}
```

Then it would be print: `123045`.

2. Same, but the added elements are always looped through at the end of the process, so, `123450`.
3. Because you have already 'passed' the point where the item got added, we no longer cover it. So, '12345' happens - the 0 is not looped over at all, because it was in front. (Remember, this is in the hypothetical world where, had we added it to the back, it *would* have been looped over!)
4. Our loop system is index based and by adding an element in front we in fact repeat. So, the code would end up printing `1233456` (because when we are on index 2, which is item `3` in the list, we add that 0, and the next loop will go with index 3. Which is.. also a `3`, because we shifted that 3 one 'to the right' after inserting that 0).

**All of these are reasonable interpretations**. Some perhaps less reasonable, but none of these 4 options are ridiculous. Therefore, then, this loop construct is kinda useless! After all, if we actually use this power of 'hey you can mess with the thing during your loop and the documentation explains precisely how that is dealt with', then we have created code that most people simply cannot properly understand (or, worse, will *think* does one thing when it actually does another. Misleading code is even worse than hard-to-read code!) - and thus probably lots of style guides will pop up saying that you should never do it. And endless debates will be held about what choice was right.

Now imagine the same kinds of questions but now in the face of having adding and removed whole boatloads of items in the middle of a loop. We wouldn't have 4 choices, we'd have tens. All plausible. All different.

Hence, we come to a simple conclusion: **It is bad language design if modification of a list during a loop is allowed in the first place**, and thus we get to why iterators solves the entire problem in one fell swoop by simply stating that you cannot continue to use an iterator once the underlying collection has been modified. Which is exactly how they work.

So why does the basic `for (int i = 0; i < col.size(); i++) { Elem e = col.get(i); /* code here */ }` work fine?

Because that code doesn't actually say; "Loop a list". That code says: "run `int i = 0`. Then, run `i < col.size()` - if that is `false`, go the `}`. If that is true, execute the code block. Then, run `i++`. Then, run `i < col.size()`; if that is `false`, go to `}` and otherwise repeat this song and dance routine.

That's literally what it says. We simply this in our human brains with 'do for each element in the collection' but that is **not what that code says**. Hence, it is not possible for the langspec to second guess that song and dance routine. It has to do precisely what you say, which results in, more or less, the behaviour of option 4 above (if you add a 6 at the end, it would be included; if you add a 0 at the front, you repeat the element you were on).

That's not a good thing. But that is what the code means, and java can't change the literal meaning by decreeing that, what, exactly? The compiler detects this pattern, goes: "I know what you wrote, but what you **meant** is to loop the list and what you've done is created something that is quite confusing so I will refuse to compile it?" - that really isn't how programming works. Computer does what you tell it to. No more. No less.

### You wonder how iterator 'knows' it was modified

Because iterators are simple objects that just hold very little state, along with a link to their origin collection. If you write:

```
List<Integer> list = List.of(1,2,3,4,5);
for (Integer i : list) { ... }
```

The iterator that is meant just remembers the index you last checked (starting at 0), and a reference (i.e. a pointer - not a copy, just, another reference to the same list) to the underlying list.

What it *also* stores is the list's 'iterator-tracking-number'. This is an arbitrarily chosen number that is incremented by 1 every time the list is modified in any way. Every modifying method (`clear()`, `remove()`, `addAll()`, `retainIf`, etcetera) starts with `iteratorTrackingNumber++`.

And, every iterator made stores the tracking number as it was when it was made, and checks if the underlying collection still has the same tracking number as what it stored. If it does not, `throw new ConcurrentModificationException()`.

It does this effort **because** of the fact that it is bad programming design to allow it.

### You wonder how one should go about modifying a thing during iteration

There is no singular answer to this question; it depends on the exact nature of the job. *Why* are you doing this?

For example, if your only intent is to inspect each element in the list to check if it has a certain property, and if so, to remove it, then this won't work as you found out:

```
for (Elem e : list) {
  if (shouldBeTossed(e)) list.remove(e);
```

and this will compile and run, but will NOT DO THE JOB:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  Elem e = list.get(i);
  if (shouldBeTossed(e)) list.remove(i);
}
```

This will skip elements; if the idea is to toss '3 and 4' from the list `List.of(1,2,3,4,5)`, then the above code would only toss 3. After all, given that it is index based, on 3 you remove 3, the next iteration, as it goes by index, will check 5. The 4 is never tossed. This:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1); list.add(2); list.add(3); list.add(4); list.add(5);
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  int elem = list.get(i);
  if (elem == 3 || elem == 4) list.remove(i);
}
System.out.println(list);
```

LOOKS, by eyeball inspection, to produce the output `[1, 2, 5]`. But it actually prints `[1, 2, 4, 5]`. Which is confusing. No programming language is going to somehow eliminate the possibility of writing confusing code, but this is a simple way to show that 'modify a list while iterating over it by index' is a really bad idea. It WILL result in misleading code (as in, what it appears to be by eyeball inspection is not what it does).

So, that's also no good.

But there's this:

```
list.removeIf(p -> p == 3 || p == 4);
```

Which will work great, is very short, and is NOT misleading. That really will result in a list containing 1, 2, and 5 only.

If you have to add new things to the end of a list, instead make a new list, during the loop add items to the new list, then after the loop, `collection.addAll(stuffToAdd);`. This code is non-ambiguous: Anybody that reads it will know immediately what it does - which is, loop over all items as the list is *before* modifying it, then all the elements to be added will be, but won't also be iterated over, as they are only added after the loop has fully finished.

Perhaps the entire design of your app should be modified - it's hard to say without a concrete example.

### EDIT: ADDENDUM - how to remove elements

As per a comment by the original question asker, it's specifically about removing stuff.

See the `removeIf` trick above. If you don't want to mess with lambdas or you can't, get the iterator, which has a remove method which you can use (because its behaviour is obvious, and therefore there is no risk of folks misunderstanding code, and therefore it works that way - and of course, that way is specced):

```
var list = new ArrayList<Integer>(List.of(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));
var it = list.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
  var v = it.next();
  if (v == 2 || v == 4) it.remove();
}
System.out.println(list);
```

The above would end up printing `[1, 3, 5]`. You can no longer use the enhanced for loop, you'll have to use a `while`, but what you're writing here *is* what the enhanced for loop literally does (you can `javac` both versions then use `javap` to see the differences. Other than line number tables, there will be no differences) - except, this way, you have a reference to the iterator, so that you can call `remove()` on it.

If, instead, you determine in the loop for element X that some element Y must be removed (i.e. not 'the element that is the topic of *this* loop, but, some other element'), then, it's trickier. You have only 2 options:

1. clone the entire list, and remove in the clone.
2. Maintain a 'to be deleted' separate list, do your loops, and once the loops are done, call `.removeAll()`, passing the `toBeDeleted` list.

If removeAll has performance issues, you *can* save indices instead, but if you do that, to remove all elements in the list at one of the 'to be removed' indices, you have to ensure that index list is sorted, and that you then loop through this sorted list of indices to remove **in reverse order**. If you want to remove the elements at index 0 and 2, and you first call `.remove(0)`, then the thing that *was* at index 2 is now at index 1. Hence why you need to worry about that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. In my case since i only want to remove elements, would saving the indecies of the elements that need to be removed, and then removing them after the loop ends be a valid approach?

Comment: @Mio I have added a section to the answer specifically tailored to 'I want to remove elements in the list while iterating through it'.

Comment: Modifying the for loop to decrement `i` every time `elem` is removed should also do the trick well:
`for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
  int elem = list.get(i);
  if (elem == 3 || elem == 4) list.remove(i--);
}`
(Code block doesn't look well in comments, sorry)

Comment: @Senozoid you're misusing the word _well_ there, I think - `.removeAll()` is the far more readable option. Whichever take is done if 'remove afterwards based on a list of indices' is taken (loop-in-reverse, or your take on it), should probably have a comment up top explaining the shenanigans :)

Comment: @rzwitserloot you are right. I meant *as opposed to the iterator*. And by "well", I meant easier to read and write without being slower.